# Unique solution over non linear equations

Tags: abstract-algebra

For a system of linear equations over a field, we know 
when system has unique solution. Is there any result 
over non linear equations? I have a system of non linear
equations over $GF(2)$.

Comment: No. In order to get better help, just name the equations which you want to solve.

Comment: My equations are very long. Some contains more than 1000 monomials.